# Executable Jar File refusing to execute even with main class specified?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, executable-jar

Lately every application I create (after a clean and build), the executable file does not want to run the application.

I checked the contents of the manifest file using WinRAR and the contents (including the main class being specified) are there and matches the manifest file contents of executable jar files that do work.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling NetBeans, I have checked the file path of the `javaw` file in my computer registry and it's correct. I have tried executing the file through the command prompt with the line `java -jar "C:/Users/MyPC/Documents/NetBeansProjects/New Java Test App/dist/New_Java_Test_App.jar"`and the output that appeared was `C:\Users\MyPC>` and nothing happened

What can I do to resolve this problem so that the executable jar file for my future projects (and recent ones) execute again?

Comment: Sounds like a permissions thing.

Comment: I see spaces in your path name but no quotes around it.

Comment: But the thing is it never use to do this before. Only recently it started doing it a few days ago and I made no changes to my Netbeans since I installed it 3 months ago. If it is a permissions issue, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: @ErwinSmout I just tried with quotes now to see if it works and it's still giving the same output as before

Comment: Have you tried java -jar "C:/Users/MyPC/Documents/NetBeansProjects/New Java Test App/dist/New_Java_Test_App.jar"

Comment: @Jens Okay I just tried with the double quotations and instead of if saying it's unable to find the file, it just says `C:\Users\MyPC>` and nothing happens

Comment: @Osiris93 We do not know what your program do, so it is possible it runs fine

Comment: @Jens My program is a Swing GUI (to test the reinstallation of NetBeans). It has a label asking the user to enter their name, a jTextField where the user enter's their name, a jButton that displays the user's name from the textfield onto a jTextArea. So surely the interface should appear when I run the executable jar file?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this isn't exactly a "fix" but it's a work-around I tried that works:

When I created a project I always unchecked the box that says `Create Main Class`. I have always done this in the past and executable jar files would still execute the application after building. But that is no longer the case.

So now if I leave the `Create Main Class` box checked, it creates a class with a main method like so:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            //Blank
    }
```

I then create the actual class I want to appear on execution. Let's call it `MainFrame.java`. I then go back to the main method in the class generated when creating a project and enter the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
        mf.setVisible(true);
}
```

I then clean and build the application, double-click on the executable jar file and the `MainFrame` GUI opens as desired. It's the only process that seems to work now